# Select-Object, different output

Tags: windows, powershell, select, get, output

I am currently writing a script, that sends me an email, if a new Windows update gets released.

`Get-WindowsUpdate`

Output:

```
ComputerName Status     KB          Size Title                                                                                                                                               ------------ ------     --          ---- -----
MD-I-T-092   -------                 2MB Intel - System - 4/12/2017 12:00:00 AM - 14.28.47.630
MD-I-T-092   -------                24KB Dell Inc. - Monitor - 1/30/2018 12:00:00 AM - 
MD-I-T-092   -------                46KB Intel - System - 9/19/2017 12:00:00 AM - 11.7.0.1000
MD-I-T-092   -------                 9MB Lenovo Ltd. - Firmware - 1.0.0.50
MD-I-T-092   -------               346KB Lenovo Ltd. - Firmware - 1.0.0.41
```

At the moment, only "Driver" updates are available. When a Windows update is available, I want to retrieve the "KB" Number and the "Title" of the update.

`Get-WindowsUpdate | Select-Object -Property KB (or Size/Title etc.)`

This method doesent work.

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zMfp.png)

I guess that is because the Property is not available.

`Get-WindowsUpdate | Select -Property *`

[All Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5mIc.png)

As this method (https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b7e3b522-04b5-4cd5-a228-837deff9d7b8/windows-update-powershell-module-display-category-with-getwindowsupdate-aka-getwulist-cmdlet?forum=ITCG) didnt work for me, do you have any other ideas on how to filter the output?
On StackO I have not found an article that helped me, but if you know one, please let me know :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are using the [PsWindowsUpdate](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PSWindowsUpdate/2.2.0.3) module.
It seems that module is poorly written and doesn't emit nice useable objects by default.

You can get at them like this:

`(Get-WindowsUpdate).GetEnumerator() | Where-Object KB -ne '' | Select-Object KB, Size, Title`.

Which gives output like this (assuming matching updates are found):

```
KB        Size  Title
--        ----  -----
KB5011644 697MB SQL Server 2019 RTM Cumulative Update (CU) 16 KB5011644
KB5014356 457MB Security Update for SQL Server 2019 RTM GDR (KB5014356)
KB5013887 67MB  2022-06 Cumulative Update for .NET Framework 3.5 and 4.8 for Windows 10 Version 21H2 for x64 (KB5013887)
KB2267602 789MB Security Intelligence Update for Microsoft Defender Antivirus - KB2267602 (Version 1.367.1700.0)
```

Comment: I am going to mark this as answer. Could you explain the Code ? I.x. "-ne". Or can you link a docu ? Thanks!

Comment: `Where-Object KB -ne ''` means "only pass along objects where the 'KB' property isn't an empty string".  As you were only interested in updates with a 'KB' this should weed out everything else.  You can drop it if you want all updates, including ones without an associated KB number.  `-ne` is one of PowerShell's [comparison operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#comparison-operators)

Comment: Also, the `GetEnumerator()` is a [.NET method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerable.getenumerator?view=net-6.0) used to enumerate the items in some collections.  `Get-WindowsUpdate` is outputting an entire collection rather than a stream/array of objects like most other cmdlets.  Another place you often need to use this in PowerShell is with [Hashtables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-hashtable?view=powershell-7.2#getenumerator)

Comment: Nicely done. Note that `(Get-WindowsUpdate) | ...` - i.e. use of `( )` around a command in a pipeline context - is sufficient to force enumeration.

Answer (score 1):

The properties you're looking for aren't available because the `Get-WindowsUpdate` returns the collection of objects as a whole rather than streaming the elements one by one (like most cmdlets do). In which case, you would have been able to retrieve the individual properties from the objects.

[image: Windows Update Collection]

In order to get the information you're looking for, first pipe the `Get-WindowsUpdate` cmdlet to the `ForEach-Object` cmdlet and then select your properties from there.

```
Get-WindowsUpdate | ForEach-Object { $_ | Select Title, KB, Size }
```

Here's what I get with that:

[image: Windows Update Properties]

Comment: Your wording is a bit confusing, given that arrays are collections too. More accurately, the command unexpectedly outputs a collection _as a whole_, instead of _streaming (outputting) its elements one by one_, as is expected in PowerShell. Enclosing a command call in `(...)` in the context of a pipeline is sufficient to force enumeration of its output; therefore: `(Get-WindowsUpdate) | Select Title, KB, Size`